# Путь к компилятору c#. JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, компилятор, jetbrains, rider

Не могу отыскать компилятор в JetBrains Rider. Прошу указать путь к папке в которой он находится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор csc.exe не часть Rider - а часть .Net Framework, который ставится с ОС Windows и находится в  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.X.XXX или Framework64

См. тж.:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6660512/5752652